# Galvanized fasteners into exterior concrete - good enough for 20+ years? Or stainless?

Tags: concrete, fastener, pressure-treated, stainless

Planning to attach pressure treated wood sleepers to a concrete patio and put deck boards over them.

I'm trying to decide on *what fastener material is best* to attach the sleepers to the concrete.

This is a wet exterior location. The concrete is bound to hold moisture pretty much all the time. (Using treated lumber means I have to use at least galvanized fasteners anyway.)

But I'm concerned that galvanized steel will rust out before the treated wood fails which would seem like a real waste. (Won't driving fasteners into concrete scratch off some of the coating?)

**Is this concern unfounded?  Will galvanized be OK or should I just go for stainless?**

Stainless is more expensive. If its worth it, that's OK. But I don't want to waste $$$ either.

---

Note - I've not yet decided on what type of fastener - e.g., tapcons vs. wedge anchors vs. nail-set hammer drive anchors... etc.

Answer (score 2):

My first deck, years and years ago, I used galvanized lag bolts and they corroded after about 7 years. My next one I used the best deck screws available, guaranteed for the life of the deck, etc. When I had to replace a plank after 4 years, the screws were rusted and snapped off when I tried to remove them. The corrosion in both cases really hastened the rotting of the wood. My next deck I used all stainless steel screws and they have held up great. I replaced a plank after 5 years due to warping and when I removed the screws, they looked like new. There was no rotting around the screw holes either. I'd use stainless screws for the wood to wood and stainless lag screws and lag shields for the wood to concrete. Make sure you get lumber that's meant to be in contact with the ground or concrete.